# Get URL of page that isn't appearing in the search bar? Google instant

Tags: javascript, ajax, search, google-chrome-extension, google-instant

I'm developing an extension and I've run into a problem... I'm wondering how would I grab the URL's of a Google instant search page? Since the browsers http bar doesn't update! I would really appreciate any help with this!

Google instant appears to be using ajax to generate it's results. I need a way of grabbing the new URL when the page updates.

Comment: To check if it's a Google Instance page, look for `#po-on-message` which `display` value is not `hidden`

Answer (score 1):

The hash part of the URL is updated a few seconds after the last typed key.

If you can't wait, you could be able to build the URL by serializing the search form:

```
// (jquery / pseudo code)
var base = $('form[name="gs"]').attr('action');
var params = $('form[name="gs"]').serialize();
var url = base + '?' + params;
```

The resulting URL will be similar to what it would have looked if the user submitted the form.

Comment: this solution does not work if the query is changed. It returned `undefined`.

Comment: what _returns_ undefined ? why ?

Comment: both base and params if I call this code from a listener repeatedly. My `window.location` isn't updating when Google instant does.

Comment: this would mean that the form element is removed from the tree during instant search ?