# serializing form doesn't update with listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, serialization, listener

Hey guys, I'm wondering can someone help me out. I'm 
                using javascript to serialize a search form. It's working.. 
                   however, if the user changes the query (backspacing, typing 
                   more, etc.) it doesnt update (I'm using a listener) and throws back undefined. How 
                   would  fix this? http://pastebin.com/edVmQ3si

EDIT: Just to clarify, the listener is working. It's just getting undefined when looking for the values from the code I linked.

Listener just calls the function which executes the code linked.

Comment: You should post all relevant code here, including the "listener."

Comment: Something like http://jsfiddle.net would be nice.

Comment: Related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843192/get-url-of-page-that-isnt-appearing-in-the-search-bar-google-instant) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843489/javascript-serializing-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach it to the `keyup` event...

```
var searchInput = $('form[name="gs"]'),
    searchForm = searchInput.closest('form'); // Thanks Matt Ball

var base = searchInput.attr('action');

searchInput.keyup(function() {
    var params = searchForm.serialize();
    var url = base + '?' + params;  
    // Do what you need with url.  
});
```

Comment: How about just using `.closest()`?

Comment: @Matt Ball To identify the `form`? Edit: Just read about it - seems to be more appropriate (I thought `closest()` meant it may search siblings as well.)